# Show that $2\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}$ satisfies $x^3+x^2-2x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

Show that $2\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}$ satisfies $x^3+x^2-2x+1$

I need to use Galois Theory. I know about the identity $\cos 3\theta = 4\cos^3 -\cos \theta$, but I can't fit things into the polynomial.

Comment: You mean $x^3+x^2-2x+1=0$. Right?

Comment: No, he meant $x^3+x^2-2x-1\ddot\smile$ @JaideepKhare

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638874/factor-z7-1-into-linear-and-quadratic-factors-and-prove-that-cos-pi-7-c/638896

Comment: @JaideepKhare WA???

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown WolframAlpha. Btw, why don't you edit the question and correct it?

Comment: @JaideepKhare  I do **not** use Wolfie A $\ddot\frown$. Would you use it to compute $2+2$?

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1405365/11619).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2545166/300700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}=\Phi_7(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^6$

It has his zeros in $\exp(\frac{2\pi i k}{7})$ with $k \in [0,1]$

If $\alpha$ is a root of $\Phi_7$ then $$\left(\alpha^3 +\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\right)+\left(\alpha^2 +\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)+\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha^1}\right)+1=0$$
$$\left(\alpha^2 +\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)=\left(\alpha +\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)^2-2$$
$$\left(\alpha^3 +\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\right)-\left(\alpha +\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\left(\alpha^2-1 +\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)=\left(\alpha^3 +\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\right)-3\left(\alpha +\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$$

Consider $x=\left(\alpha +\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$ and you obtain:
$$x^3-3x+x-2+x^2+1=0$$

At the end you obtain $$x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$

When $\alpha=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{7}\right)$ you get $x=2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

You could use $\cos7\theta=T_7(\cos\theta)$
where $T_7$ is the seventh Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind (q.v.).

Or just write
$$2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}=\newcommand{\ze}{\zeta}\ze+\ze^{-1}$$
where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/7)$ and compute
$$x^3+x^2-2x-1=(\ze+\ze^{-1})^3+(\ze+\ze^{-1})^2-2(\ze+\ze^{-1})-1
=\ze^3+\ze^2+\ze+1+\ze^{-1}+\ze^{-2}+\ze^{-3}=\frac{\ze^4-\ze^{-3}}{\ze-1}
=0$$
as $\ze^7=1$.

Comment: If I am not wrong, is $\zeta =e^{i2\pi/7}$? I don't understand what Chebyshev polynomial is... That's why asking.

Comment: @JaideepKhare For more on Chebyshev polynomials, see Wikipedia. Anyway, what I wrote does completely characterise $T_7\,\ddot\smile$.

Comment: Ok Thanks! ☺ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score -1):

If $7x=2m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

$4x=2m\pi-3x$

$\cos4x=\cos3x$

$2(2c^2-1)^2-1=4c^3-3c$ where $c=\cos x$

$\iff8c^4-4c^3-8c^2+1=0$

Now if $7\mid m,c=1$

So, if $7\nmid m$  $$\dfrac{8c^4-4c^3-8c^2+1}{c-1}=0$$